# Sharepoint 2013/2016 and Custom Web Api with custom database.

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps, sharepoint-2016, sharepoint-webservice

How do I authenticate to a Custom Web Api from a SharePoint 2013/2016 single page app? I've seen a couple examples of using session which i really don't want to use, I'm thinking maybe a custom security token service or would it be better to add the web api as a provider hosted app (high trust) since this is on premises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found  a solution finally, this one actually makes sense: http://blog.baslijten.com/getting-sharepoint-2013-apps-and-webapi-to-work/

Comment: Sorry to answer so late but I have been away for few weeks. Yes but I ended up not using it and just doing normal SPA with angular 4 and ASOS for my Authorization Server with windows which works way better than SharePoint stuff. I would prob just use the SharePoint Framework SPFx with React for anything with the rest api but anything custom I'm keeping out of SP, the app framework is clunky like the rest of MS stuff.